# horizontal scrollbar issue with Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, scroll, horizontal-scrolling

Demo:
http://jayacemerlangindustries.com/bonze

Screenshot:
http://tinypic.com/r/a3mj3d/8

How to remove the horizontal scroll?

Comment: There's no need for server access. This is a matter of learning to use your favorite browser's developer tools (Chrome, Firefox and IE11 are best).

Answer (score 0):

Put `overflow: hidden` on `#about` and `#wedo` for a quick fix:

Like:

```
<style>
    #about, #wedo {overflow: hidden;}
</style>
```

Comment: hello thank you so much for your advice, i've put overflow:hodden; but it's still not work.. http://tinypic.com/r/w8pa42/8 , what a tiny problem with this? browser or code? i really appreciate with your advice? :)

Comment: I don't see a scrollbar on your site in Chrome.